# It's possible to set <tr> height of element that has 'display:table-row'?

Tags: html, css, gridjs

I'm using  [grid.js](https://gridjs.io/) to render a table in a webpage.
Having a fixed-height table expressed in vh units (`60vh`), with less rows than the pagination limit i got this strange effect:

[gridjs-tablerow-height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dJc5.png)
A single row that stretches out to fit the `<tbody>`
There is a way to override the height set by `display:table-row`?

I tried assigning "height tags" with !important.

```js
new gridjs.Grid({
  columns: ["Name", "Email", "Phone Number"],
  data: [
    ["John", "john@example.com", "(353) 01 222 3333"],
  ],
  height: '80vh'
}).render(document.getElementById("coolTable"));
```

```css
.gridjs-tr {
    line-height: 20px !important;
    max-height: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/gridjs/dist/theme/mermaid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gridjs/dist/gridjs.umd.js"></script>

<div id="coolTable"></div>
```

Comment: Please show us a runnable snippet so we can see for ourselves. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Unsetting the height in the constructor fixes it.

```js
this.grid = new gridjs.Grid({
    columns: this.cols,
    pagination: true,
    fixedHeader: true,
    /*height: '800px',*/
    data: data,
    search:true,
    }).render(document.getElementById("wrapper"));
}
```